# Text classification algorithms for small sets

Tags: classification, text-mining

I'm trying to classify a set of 1656 tweets into different categories.  I've read about different classification algorithms (supervised and unsupervised) but I'm really concerned because my set and the document text are small.

Which algorithm would you recommend for classifying small sets with small documents such as tweets?

P.S: I don't want to train a model with this data, I just need to classify this tweets into categories as an input for another task.

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are 1656 tweets enough? That depends first and foremost on your task. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198448/how-to-estimate-the-number-of-samples-needed-for-nlp-corpus/200156#200156) for more information.

**Supervised or unsupervised?**

Can you give (at least) one category for most documents? Then it is supervised.

**Small sets vs large sets**

For most scenarios in text classification, linear SVMs (Liblinear) work very well. Twitter data is somewhat harder to handle because of things like colloquial language, misspellings, abbreviations, hashtags...etc.
However, if you clean and preprocess your data quite good, the algorithms work the same as usual.